# Flask SQLAlchemy custom method

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy, marshmallow

I have a Flask SQLAlchemy model and I wanted to create a custom method named "uuid" and use it in the API response.

This is the custom method i want to create inside model. Where and how to create this in Flask Model?

```
def uuid():
    "br-%s", self.id
```

Here is the current model:

```
from app import db
from marshmallow import fields

class Build(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'builds'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    product = db.Column(db.String(200))
    # uuid = "build_<id_field>"

class BuildSchema(ma.Schema):
    class Meta:
        fields = ('id',
                  'uuid',
                  'product')

build_schema = BuildSchema()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way of doing this would be using the [built-in `@property` decorator](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#property):

```
from app import db
from marshmallow import fields

class Build(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'builds'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    product = db.Column(db.String(200))

    @property
    def uuid(self) -> str:
        return "br-%s" % self.id

class BuildSchema(ma.Schema):
    
    id = ma.fields.Integer()
    uuid = ma.fields.String()
    product = ma.fields.String()
```